# matlab scientific vs exponential notation

Tags: matlab, notation, approximation

I have a problem with Matlab. Mainly `5*10^-15!=5e-15`.
Depending on how I declare a number (`e` or `10^`) it is different saved (`5.000000000000001` vs. `5.000000000000000`). It makes problems with comparing values declared with calculated (declared were with 10^, matlab saves calculations with e).

Anyone has some idea why does it happen? It is some kind of matlab's approximation?

For now I can declare everything in scientific notation, but then if I would like to make exponent a variable `A` I would have problem with writing e.g. `5eA`.

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: Another case of floating point errors. I would suggest to read into the basics here (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with precision errors and tolerances. The way to deal with it is to compare the difference as opposed to a tolerance level, ex;

```
eps = 0.00000001
if (abs(a-b) < eps) //success
```